# Magento2 - How to show both billing and shipping address in user registration form

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, billing-address, customer-registration

I want to show both the billing address and shipping address form in a user-registration page and save the data .

Answer (score 1):

display address fields using customer_account_create.xml as below:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
   <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="show_address_fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
    </arguments>
 </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

In template file already value set as 1 for both default_billing and default_shipping fields as 1, so by default billing and shipping, both addresses got to save the as same address.

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

```
<input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1">
```

Comment: here I can only save one address the address as default billing and default shipping i want two forms that one store as default billing and another one default shipping

Comment: Did you find any solution to achieve this ?

Comment: Its not working